# executing javascript function from HTML without event

Tags: javascript, function, events

I wish to call a javascript function from an HTML page and I **do not** want it dependent on any event.  The function is in a separate .js file since I wish to use it from many web pages. I am also passing variables to it.  I've tried this:

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="fp_footer2.js">
footerFunction(1_basic_web_page_with_links, 1bwpwl.html);
</script>
```

The function in fp_footer2.js:

```
function footerFunction(path, file) {

document.write("<a href=" + path + "/" + file + " target='_blank'>Link to the original web page for this assignment.</a>");

return;
}
```

(I have also tried putting the fp_footer2.js file reference in the header, to no avail.  I'm not sure if I can put it 'inline' like I did in this example. If not, please let me know.

PS: I know I can do this with a simple 'a href=""' in the HTML itself.  I wanted to see if this could work, for my own curiosity.

Comment: look at the errors in your console, set-up a fiddle, and remember that `document.write` will overwrite the DOM, and take the scripts you loaded with it

Comment: You need quotes around the parameters you are passing into the function, but yes, you can execute arbitrary javascript without tying to an event just as you have done.

Comment: I'm confused, if you don't want it fired with an event, when exactly do you want it fired?

Comment: `1bwpwl.html` probably needs to be `"1bwpwl.html"`

Comment: If a script block has a `src` defined, anything within the block will be ignored.

Answer (score 7):

If a `<script>` has a `src`, then the external script replaces the inline script.

You need to use *two* script elements.

The strings you pass to the function also need to be actual strings and not undefined variables (or properties of undefined variables). String literals must be quoted.

```
<script src="fp_footer2.js"></script>
<script>
    footerFunction("1_basic_web_page_with_links", "1bwpwl.html");
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that snippet, that worked fine!  So I made two mistakes: not having quotes around the strings and trying to use a single script element.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript will run **while** your page is being rendered. A common mistake is to execute a script that tries to access an element further down the page. This fails because the element isn't there when the script runs.

So includes in the `<head>` will run *before* any DOM content is available.

If your scripts are dependent on the existence of DOM elements (like a footer!) try to put the script includes *after* the DOM element. A better solution is to use the `document ready` event (`$(document).ready()` in jQuery). Or `window.onload`.

The difference between `documen ready` and `window onload` is that `document ready` will fire when the DOM has been rendered; so all initial DOM elements will be available. Where as `window onload` fires after all resources have loaded, like images. `window onload` is useful if you're doing things with those images. Usually `document ready` is the right one.

Comment: All the code is in the question. None of it tries to access an element that isn't available yet. It also uses `document.write` which has to run *before* the document is ready!

Comment: Where? (And you still can't `document.write` after `document.close` has been trigged by the DOM parsing finishing: http://jsfiddle.net/cZZTg/ )

Comment: Then I would argue not to use `document.write`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand your question, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="fp_footer2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   footerFunction(1_basic_web_page_with_links, 1bwpwl.html);
</script>
```

Comment: @Quentin Ah, just noticed that the same `script` tag had a reference to an external file and some inline script. See my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried calling it from a document.ready?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    footerFunction(1_basic_web_page_with_links, 1bwpwl.html);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: That `$` function is undefined. If jQuery was loaded, then this would attempt to document.write after the DOM was ready … which is not something you should try to do. (because it is too late: http://jsfiddle.net/cZZTg/ )