# Executing JavaScript function from an HTML element (<span>) with no conditions but with arguments

Tags: javascript, html, css, attributes

I want to do this

```js
document.getElementById('demo1').style.color = "red";
document.getElementById('demo2').style.color = "blue";
document.getElementById('demo3').style.color = "green";
document.getElementById('demo4').style.color = "fuchsia";
```

```html
<p id="demo1">Styled text</p>
<p id="demo2">Styled text</p>
<p id="demo3">Styled text</p>
<p id="demo4">Styled text</p>
```

But don't want to do it that way, this is better:

```js
function style(obj, color) {
  obj.style.color = color;
}
```

```html
<p call="style(this, 'red')">Styled text</p>
<p call="style(this, 'blue')">Styled text</p>
<p call="style(this, 'green')">Styled text</p>
<p call="style(this, 'fuchsia')">Styled text</p>
```

But this doesn't work. I am looking for some DRY way of styling text, and the first way is very tedious. The JavaScript way is pleasant, as it allows for more flexibility (like adding `fontFamily` in the parameters). Is there some HTML attribute that can work like `call` above? Is there some other way of styling text that is just as good? I thought about `onload`, but that works only for [certain selected tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41176554/13679974).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237215/executing-javascript-function-from-html-without-event) related question comes close, but it is about a web page, not about a specific HTML tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try creating your own `call` attribute of the sort. Only thing is `this` won't work - you'll have to reference it through the parent function.

```js
function style(obj, color) {
  obj.style.color = color;
}
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(elem => eval(elem.getAttribute('data-call')));
```

```html
<p data-call="style(elem, 'red');">Styled text</p>
<p data-call="style(elem, 'blue')">Styled text</p>
<p data-call="style(elem, 'green')">Styled text</p>
<p data-call="style(elem, 'fuchsia')">Styled text</p>
```